# How to get the url of the page which is currently loading in the iframe

Tags: asp.net

I have an requirement that, in my application on clicking an button I have to load one more application with the same template which I was using for my application.

So, on clicking the button in my application I have used one intermediate page in that using iframe I passed that URL of an external application. Its working fine.

But the problem is in the external application which is not in my control on clicking an button it is moving to next page. In that page I want to hide an button.

I did that also using div tag color as white and set the positions.

But the problem is in all the pages in the same position that is affecting. So I want to get the URL of the page which is loading in the iframe on the second or third click of an external application, so that I can using some conditions I can hide the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript.  Give the iframe an ID

```
var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
```

The url is accessible via the "src" attribute:

```
iframe.src
```

[more info](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/iframe.html)